# Auto-store datetime() value in select insert query mysql

Tags: mysql

need an advice, how to auto-store datetime value for my historyActivity table in select insert mysql query. This is an example:

```
INSERT INTO history_sequence(CODE, LAST_MOUNTH, LAST_VALUE) SELECT CODE, MOUNTH, VALUE FROM seq WHERE CODE = CODEVALUE
```

i just want to add datetime to see time when the data inserted. Need help please

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the MySQL table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE history_sequence ADD inserted TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

When records are inserted into the table table, the `inserted` column gets automatically populated with the current timestamp.

Comment: Delighted to hear it, @UgyAstro. Assuming you're satisfied, could you please accept the answer? i.e. click on the green 'tick' below the up/down arrows.